# Using a shell script to check if rsync made any changes

Tags: unix, bash, rsync, unix-shell

I've got a bash script that rsync's two directories.  Sometimes there's a change, odds are there's nothing.

I want to run a command only if rsync actually made a change (add/update a file).  Otherwise I want to just skip it.  Is there a return response I should be looking at?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use the -i option (and don't use the -v option), rsync will only print lines to STDOUT for any changes that were made. Depending on your script, this could look like

```
if [ -n "$(rsync -i /dir1 /dir2)" ]; then
  run_command;
fi
```

Comment: That seems to do exactly what I want... thanks.  Didn't think of using the -i flag like that.

Comment: To clarify, if you want to run the script _only_ if a change was made, then `==` should be `!=`.

Comment: Well as it is, this code is wrong from what I have seen.
As for that code you get it Rsync ran FINE or HAS ERROR running, but this code doesn't check if there was a change. I don´t know if other version of Rsync could that, but I´m using RSYNC in Raspbmc (an old implementation we have) and OSMC. This is sad as RSYNC seems to be a wonderful tool.

Comment: With the `-i` flag - rsync version `3.1.1` outputs `sending incremental file list` when no changes are made.